# Linebreak Javascript InnerText

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i have made a simple note application that displays notes in a card style with a headline and all that.
Now i have a problem. When people type into the  without pressing enter to move to the next line when writing a sentence the notecard also displays it the way it got it from the textarea.
However i want it to put breaks between the lines so it does not overflow in the notecard.

Here a picture: It should be like the bottom note, but it is like the first one.
https://gyazo.com/4d3d75908b7eccb64522be67f621530e

What code wheter CSS or javascript do i need to add?

**I have already put a max-width of 90% for the card paragraph but it seems to just ignore it and just overflow.**

```
// Main Variables

let noteForm = document.querySelector("form");
let headlineInput = document.getElementById("headline-input");
let noteInput = document.getElementById("note-input");
let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
let noteSection = document.getElementById("notes");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let currentNotes = document.getElementById("current-notes");

// Create Elements on Click

function addElement() {

    if (headlineInput.value.length == 0 || (noteInput.value.length == 0)){
        console.log("Input value null");
        return;
    }
    //Create all elements

    let noteCard = document.createElement("div");
    noteSection.appendChild(noteCard);
    noteCard.className = "notecard";

    let noteHead = document.createElement("h2");
    noteCard.appendChild(noteHead);
    noteHead.className = "note-headline";

    let noteParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    noteCard.append(noteParagraph);
    noteParagraph.className = "note-paragraph";
```

```
.notecard {
    border:1px solid rgb(243, 242, 242);
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    margin-bottom:50px;
    padding:20px;
}
.notecard h2 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #16e0bd;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.notecard p {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    color:rgb(59, 59, 59);
    font-size:15px;
    max-width:900px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! You can give a width to the displaying container which should do it but if it doesn't you could try the overflow css property. I see you already gave a max width but maybe 900px is too high? If you make a js fiddle I could poke around and see.

Comment: @AlePlo Hey, yea here: https://jsfiddle.net/trhwm0pq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I styled the note-paragraph like this (I've set the width in px but it should be the same as the container above.

```
.note-paragraph{
  width: 500px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow: auto;
    word-break: break-all;
  
}
```

You can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/e9zdxomy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Move `max-width:900px;` to `.notecard`